# How to set a linear gradient in a color map in Sass

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I'm trying to set a linear gradient in a color map in my ionic 2 project but just keep getting an error.

```
$color (
  light:    #fefefe,
  dark:     #333,
  cool:     linear-gradient('#0005de', '#12dfff')
)
```

How do i set the linear-gradient

Comment: `@include linearGradient(#0005de, #12dfff);`

Comment: A couple of things are wrong with your code. First of all you've defined a variable `$color` wrongly, you've left out the colon. Your code should be `$color` **:** `(...). Secondly your values for `light` and `dark` are wrong. When using hex values for colours, you can use either **3** or **6** characters whereas in your code you've used **5** which will eventually throw an error. I also don't think the quotation marks for the colours passed in the linear-argument function are necessary.

Comment: Where do i add the @include linearGradient(#0005de, #12dfff);

Answer (score 2):

The setup of your map should look a little something like this:

```
$color: (
  light: #444,
  dark: #111,
  cool: linear-gradient(#0005de, #12dfff)
);
```

Note: if you want to change the rotation of the linear gradient, you should use a syntax like this `linear-gradient(45deg, #0005de, #12dfff)`. Also, #111 is darker than #444.

To use the colour as a property value, you will have to use the map-get function like so:

```
.selector {
  background: map-get($color, cool);
}
```

Comment: Actually the cool: linear-gradient(#0005de, #12dfff); of the code throws an error

Comment: Ah, I've spotted my mistake. There shouldn't be a semi-colon at the end of the `linear-gradient`. I will edit the answer so that there's some working code there.